# Host is missing hostname and/or domain

Tags: domain, hostname

i use puppet 0.25.4 on ubuntu 10.04,when puppet installed ,i got the infor below :
Nov 29 10:30:30 puppet puppetmasterd[4422]: Host is missing hostname and/or domain: pclient.example.com

Nov 29 10:30:30 puppet puppetmasterd[4422]: Compiled catalog for pclient.example.com in 0.02 seconds

```
i dont know how to fix it ,who can help me 

thank you !

my configuration :
I use apt-get to install the puppet,so some configuration have been fixed 
puppet.conf on client :

> [main] server=puppet.example.com
> logdir=/var/log/puppet
> vardir=/var/lib/puppet
> ssldir=/var/lib/puppet/ssl
> rundir=/var/run/puppet
> factpath=$vardir/lib/facter
> pluginsync=false
> templatedir=$confdir/templates
> prerun_command=/etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-pre
> postrun_command=/etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-post
> certname=pclient.example.com
> node_name=cert [puppetd]
> runinterval=30
```

puppet.conf on server:

```
> [main] logdir=/var/log/puppet
> vardir=/var/lib/puppet
> ssldir=/var/lib/puppet/ssl
> rundir=/var/run/puppet
> factpath=$vardir/lib/facter
> pluginsync=true
> templatedir=$confdir/templates
> prerun_command=/etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-pre
> postrun_command=/etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-post
```

i user the default node on site.pp

i am a newer to puppet,so i dont know the reason for these problems!!

thank you again!!!

Comment: I have seen it and tried it ,but it didnt work.

Answer (score 3):

Puppet get it's default domain from the domain declaration in /etc/resolv.conf. It takes it from the last domain declaration even if commented out.

Answer (score 1):

Have you searched for "Puppet" on ServerFault before asking the question?

Please look at:

[Puppet: Node name seems dependent on reverse dns?](https://serverfault.com/questions/66138/puppet-node-name-seems-dependent-on-reverse-dns)

and see if this might be applicable in your situation?

Otherwise, please describe your configuration.